# How to insert a line after a particular pattern?

Tags: sed

I am trying to insert a pattern named "no comments"  after line "3 3 1 May  7 05:31:11 2019" in the following sample file

```
INV_YTEC_TR::
3 3 1 May  7 05:31:11 2019
CA AOI1 0 0 -1 -3176120 1602000 12
A 0.4
```

**Tried following sed code but it didn't help.**

```
sed -i 's/\(^\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\d+.*$\)/\1\nno comments/ig' tmp.txt
```

Could someone please help me with the right sed command?

Regards,
Shikha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `sed` doesn’t know the `\d` shorthand, you can use either `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]` instead, and you need to enable extended regular expression (ERE) syntax with the `-r` option for `+` to be recognized as a metacharacter:

```bsh
sed -ir 's/^[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+.*/&\nno comments/' tmp.txt
```

`&` on the right is replaced with the whole match, so you don’t need to create a group. `$` at the end is not necessary if your expression ends with `.*`. The `g`lobally flag makes `sed` replace all matches in the line, that’s not needed when you already match the whole line. The `i` flage makes the regex case-insensitive, but you did that already by using `[A-Za-z]` and not `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`, so you can omit that too.

Groups are not only a way to cut out parts of the match in order to use it in the replacement, they also serve as a way to combine sequences. In your case they come in handy to merge e.g.

```bsh
[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+
```

to

```bsh
([0-9]+\s+){3}
```

which shortens your regex:

```bsh
sed -ir 's/^([0-9]+\s+){3}[A-Za-z]+\s+[0-9]+\s+([0-9]+:){2}[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+.*/&\nno comments/' tmp.txt
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ <s sed -r 's/^([0-9]+\s+){3}[A-Za-z]+\s+[0-9]+\s+([0-9]+:){2}[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+.*/&\nno comments/'
INV_YTEC_TR::
3 3 1 May  7 05:31:11 2019
no comments
CA AOI1 0 0 -1 -3176120 1602000 12
A 0.4
```

#### Further reading

- [GNU sed manual chapter 5.6 regular expression extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) explaining the recognized shorthand classes